# OWIN Service resolution Using Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, autofac, owin

I have an WebApi application using OWIN and Autofac. Although controllers and parameters get resolved correctly, I would like to be able to use `OwinContext.Get<type>` to resolve types registered with Autofac. Is that posible?

Already set`app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);` and `config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);`

By example, I registered `builder.Register<IAppConfiguration>(c => new AppConfig());` and I'd like to resolve it using `owinContext.Get<IAppConfiguration>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IOwinContext.Get` uses the `Environment` dictionary, resolving objects registered directly with Owin, it does not take into account Autofac container.

I managed to do it by accessing the Autofac OwinLifetimeScope in the Environment property and using the scope to resolve the service.

You can access the LifetimeScope using this code

```
var scope=OwinContext.Get<Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope>("autofac:OwinLifetimeScope");
```

and then

```
scope.GetService(type)
```

You should check for nulls and write it in a better way, as Extension method maybe.

Comment: Doesn't work if the `autofac:OwinLifetimeScope` key has a big guid behind it. Use `owinContext.GetAutofacLifetimeScope()` instead.

Comment: My key also has a guid behind it - do you know why?

Answer (score 8):

**There is no way to get `OwinContext.Get<T>` to resolve things from Autofac.** If you dive into Microsoft.Owin.OwinContext.Get in Reflector, you'll see it's backed entirely by a dictionary of things you register with an environment. It's not dynamic and there's no way (without creating your own `IOwinContext` implementation) to get it to resolve things *either* out of the dictionary *or* out of dependency resolution.

**If you are in a `DelegatingHandler` or an `ApiController`** you will have a reference to the current `HttpRequestMessage`. Use `message.GetDependencyScope()` to get the current request-level dependency scope to resolve services.

```
public HttpResponseMessage SomeControllerAction()
{
  var service = this.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(Service));
}
```

**If you have access to the `HttpConfiguration` then you can use the `HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver`** to resolve things. Note that resolver will *not have per-request dependencies available*. Web API tracks request dependency scope with the inbound `HttpRequestMessage` so be aware of that limitation. [There is an FAQ about per-request lifetime scope](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) that can help you through that.

**If you're in a place where there's *only* an `IOwinContext`**, you may need to make use of a package like [CommonServiceLocator](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/) and the [associated Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator/). There really isn't a way to get a reference to the current `HttpConfiguration` or global container just from an `IOwinContext`. Again, if you go this route, you won't have per-request dependencies available, so be aware.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I took the sources of Katana implementation and noticed the implementation of the OwinContext which reads keys from the Environment property. Having a look at the Environment contents, I noticed the autofac:OwinLifetimeScope which gives access to the current Autofac scope. I can use that to resolve my service. An extension method did the job. Thank you

Comment: Is this just outdated @travis? `owinContext.GetAutofacLifetimeScope()` works.

Comment: Yes, that is a new extension since this answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you have WebAPI in your project, you can simulate a http request like this

```
var dependencyScope = new AutofacWebApiDependencyScope(owinContext.GetAutofacLifetimeScope());
var myService = dependencyScope.GetService(typeof(MyService));
```